# Where is $F$ defined by $F(x,y)=0$ if $x=0$ or $y=0$, $F(x,y)= x^2+y^2$ otherwise, differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Question:

Where is $F(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x=0 \text{ or }y=0  \\
      x^2+y^2 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$ differentiable?

My Attempt:

First of all, If $x\neq 0, y\neq 0$ then $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and so the partial derivatives are defined, and continious, so $F$ is $C^1$ at any such $(x,y)$.

However, if $x=0, y\neq 0$:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}|_{(0,y)}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{F(h,y)-F(0,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(h,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2+y^2}{h}$ which doesn't exist when $y\neq 0$. Hence $F$ is not differentiable at $(0,y)$ for non zero $y$.

By symetry, this is also true for $(x, 0)$. Hence $F$ is differentiable at the set $S=\{(x,y)|x\neq0, y\neq 0\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$.

Anything I missed here?

Edit:

To show $F$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, I calculate $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{F(h,0)-F(0,0)}{h}=0$. Similarly $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. So we define $T=(0 \quad 0)$. Now we check the limit of $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{||F(x,y)-F(0,0)-T((x,y)-(0,0))||}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{||F(x,y)||}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$ which goes to $0$ hence $F$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$ by definition of differentiability.

Comment: Obviously no, because it is not continuous.

Comment: @MonkeyKing Edited the question

Comment: I can't see that you have shown that $F$ is differentiable a $(0,0)$.

Comment: @md2perpe To do that, do I set $T=(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0) \quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0))$ and check the definition of differentiability showing that the limit goes to $0$?

Comment: I don't get your explanation. If you set $T=(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0) \quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0))$ then you first need $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0)$. Have you calculated those? And these are constants; what do you mean with taking the limit? Could you expand on that in your post?

Comment: @md2perpe I have added an additional edit to show what I mean. Thanks for your help

Comment: $F$ is continuous and différentiable at $\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(x,y),xy\ne 0\}$, but discontinuous elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence of points $(\frac{n+1}n,\frac1n)$; they always lie above above the $x$-axis and converge to the point $(1,0)$,  and $F$ takes a value $>1$ on all these points; hence the limit of these values will be $\geq1$

Consider another sequence $(\frac{n+1}n, 0)$ again converging to the *same point* $(1,0)$. Here $F$ (by definition) always takes the value $0$, hence the limiting value is $0$. So $F$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$. Same way you can show for any $a\ne0$ $F$ not continuous at any $(a,0)$ or $(0,a)$. SO $F$ is not differentiable at all those points.